# C# 7.3 Enum constraint: Why can't I use the enum keyword?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, c#-7.3

To constrain a generic type parameter to be of an enum type, I previously constrained them like this, which was the best I could go for constraining type T for enums in pre-C# 7.3:

```
void DoSomething<T>() where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable
```

Now, C# 7.3 adds a new feature to constrain a generic type to `System.Enum`.
I tried using the enum constraint with the [VS2017 15.7 update released today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.7#csharp), and it compiles successfully when I write it like this (given I have a `using System;` directive):

```
void DoSomething<T>() where T : Enum
```

However, using the `enum` keyword does not work and causes the compiler to throw the following errors (there are more errors following, expecting a method body, but not really worth mentioning here I guess):

```
void DoSomething<T>() where T : enum
                                ^ error CS1031: Type expected
                                  error CS1002: ; expected
                                    ^ error CS1001: Identifier expected
                                      error CS1514: { expected
                                      error CS1513: } expected
```

Since there is a `struct` constraint working for structures, I do not understand why `enum` doesn't work here for enums. It's true that `enum` does not map to an actual type like `int` would do for `Int32`, but I thought it should behave the same as the `struct` constraint.

Did I just fall into an experimental feature trap not being fully implemented yet, or was this done on purpose in the specification (why?)?

Comment: While `string` is an alias for the `String` type, the same is not true for the  `enum` keyword and the `Enum` type.

Comment: That's what I meant with my last paragraph. A `struct` constraint is not an alias for a specific type too, but is possible.

Comment: `struct` is for the value types, not just struct, similar to `class` for all reference types

Comment: check this, possible solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/79903/1559611

Comment: @MrinalKamboj It does make sense, kinda. Though I think one could argue then that those keywords handle their own specific cases, and `enum` should've done too. About your link: with C# 7.3 using `Enum` (not the keyword `enum`) would be the better solution now. The question is just why the keyword isn't meant to work (at the moment).

Comment: This implementation caught me out. My question [Why is a generic type constrained by 'Enum' failing to qualify as a 'struct'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50294032/397817) may or may not be of interest :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `struct` constraint on generics doesn't map to an actual type (though it could, in theory, map to [`ValueType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx)). Similarly, `enum` doesn't cleanly map to actual types the way `string`, `int`, or `long` do, it sets up special syntax for creating a class of symbolic constants that map to integer values; hence `public enum Stuff` instead of `public class Stuff : Enum`. Note that had the latter been implemented instead, it would be more subtle since it would change syntax based on inherited type, instead of changing syntax based on a non-`class` keyword.

So, in conclusion, yes, `where T : enum` is not meant to work because `enum` is a keyword, not a type alias. If you *really* want to see it work because `enum` at least smells like a type alias in context like these, go request it!

EDIT: For some historical reference, [here's a question from 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum) indicating that `Enum` was not a valid constraint, since it's a special class.

Comment: I guess this is the best explanation so far. I couldn't find others on GitHub where the implementation of this feature was discussed. Funny enough, people there originally provided samples which also used the `enum` keyword, but it wasn't implemented like that in the end.

Comment: @RayKoopa Also, I am a bit surprised that if you have just `where T : Enum`, then the compiler will allow you to use the abstract base type `System.Enum` itself (a reference type!) for `T`. So you could `DoSomething<Enum>();`. To avoid that, it is actually legal to do `where T : struct, Enum`. To me it looks like that is what you want 99.9% of the time! Ah, I see now there is a linked thread about just this.