# Why is a generic type constrained by 'Enum' failing to qualify as a 'struct' in C# 7.3?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums, c#-7.3

If I have a generic interface with a `struct` constraint like this:

```
public interface IStruct<T> where T : struct { }
```

I can supply an enumeration as my type `T` like so, because an `enum` satisfies a `struct` constraint:

```
public class EnumIsAStruct : IStruct<DateTimeKind> { }
```

C# 7.3 added an [`Enum` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints). The following code, which was previously illegal, now compiles:

```
public class MCVE<T> : IStruct<T> where T : struct, Enum { }
```

However, to my surprise, the following fails to compile:

```
public class MCVE<T> : IStruct<T> where T : Enum { }
```

...with the error

> CS0453    The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use
>   it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IStruct'

Why is this? I would expect a generic type constrained by `Enum` to be usable as a type argument where the type is constrained by `struct` but this doesn't seem to be the case - I am having to change my `Enum` constraint to `struct, Enum`. Is my expectation wrong?

Comment: That's not really surprising since you have to repeat constraints when inheriting.  Though the tidbit about the new `Enum` constraint in your answer is interesting.

Comment: Definitely one of the reasons it was omitted from C# before.  The CLR does distinguish between System.Enum and a concrete enum type as the actual type argument (Ecma-355, chapter II.10.1.7).  That matters because System.Enum is a reference type and not a value type, values have to be boxed.  You are probably not interested in actually use System.Enum so nail it shut by adding the struct contraint.

Comment: What an absolutely useless feature.  You can constrain the type to `Enum`, but you can't do anything with it!  You can't cast it to 'int', you can't combine flags with `|`.  These all give errors: `TEnum val; var i = (int)val; //ERROR: "Cannot conver type 'TEnum' to 'int'"` or `TEnum a, b; var c = a | b; //ERROR: "Operator '|' cannot be applied to type 'TEnum' and 'TEnum'."`  Useless.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1511) is strange (arguably), but expected, behavior.

The **class `System.Enum` itself** could be supplied as the type of `T`. Being a class, `System.Enum` is of course not a `struct`!

```
public class MCVE<T> where T : Enum { }
public class MCVE2 : MCVE<Enum> { }
```

[As explained by contributor HaloFour](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1511#issuecomment-388350474):

> This is an odd behavior by the CLR itself. `System.Enum` is a class, but
>   every type that derives from `System.Enum` is a `struct`. So a constraint
>   on `System.Enum` by itself doesn't imply `struct` since you could pass
>   `System.Enum` as the generic type argument...
>
> It is weird, but it was easier to simply remove the imposed limitation
>   on the compiler than to argue over different syntax for "enum"
>   constraints that might have different behavior.

The **solution** is to make it your standard practice to constrain to `struct, Enum` when you wish to constrain concrete types to being *any specific enumeration*. If *additionally* you wish to accept the class `System.Enum` as your generic type, only then would you constrain to `Enum`.

Comment: I'm still wondering why the `enum` keyword wasn't used instead, to avoid precisely this situation.

Comment: Can't even use it like an enum. Can't cast to (int) and can't combine values with '|'. Only way to work with the TEnum generic value is to use Convert.ToInt32 and work with integers, then cast back either using `(TEnum)(object)tenumValue` or `(TEnum)Enum.ToObject(enumType,tenumValue)`, and ToObject is a terrible name (should have been FromValue) since it's documented to create an Enum object from a plain integer value. Funny thing is, this workaround works even without the use of the Enum type constraint feature, so it really is completely useless!