# Get the type of a closed type from the static constructor of the generic class that the closed type derives from

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, static

If I have a generic type with a static constructor and a constrain

```
interface IMyInterface
{
...
}

class MyGeneric<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
    static MyGeneric()
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

And a closed type:

```
class MyClass : MyGeneric<TypeImplementingIMyInterface>
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible, **through reflection**, to **retrieve the type of the closed type (MyClass) from within the static constructor in the MyGeneric**? If so, **how**?

I have tried so far without success:

- `var t = typeof(MyGeneric<>);`
- `var t = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetType()`;

I know I can use the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to do what I want:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
}

class MyBase
{

}

class MyGeneric<T1, T2> : MyBase where T1 : IMyInterface, T2 : MyBase
{
    static MyGeneric()
    {
        var t = typeof(T2);
        // ...
    }
}

class MyClass : MyGeneric<TypeImplementingIMyInterface, MyClass>
{
    // ...
}
```

**I would like to know if there is another approach that can be used in the described scenario.**

I accept a No as an answer if that is the answer.

Comment: Suppose you have 2 "closed" types inheriting from MyGeneric, which type should be chosen in your case?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936580/c-sharp-generic-static-constructor) each closed type gets its own static initialization and copy of static variables. Therefore I wonder if it exists any mecanism in System.Reflection that allows to retrieve the type for which the static constructor is being invoked. I kind of "this" retrieved through reflection wihtin the static constructor.

Comment: Yes, but closed type is `MyGeneric<TypeImplementingIMyInterface>`, not `MyClass`. You can get current closed type as usual: `typeof(MyGeneric<T>)`, but this will not be MyClass of course, because this one is completely different type.

Comment: That's true, and I think it actually answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: I would appreciate feedback on why the question was downvoted so as to do it better next time.

Comment: The downvoter has already gone and will probably not see your comment so will not reply. As for me - question is ok.

Comment: @racucad May I know what you are trying to achieve if you have access to this information? Or is this question born out of academic curiosity? I ask because I saw a pretty similar question earlier where someone wanted to know whether it was `A.Foo()` or `B.Foo()` from inside `Foo()` if it was a static method in `class A` and `class B` inherited from it. C# hides that difference.

Answer (score 0):

Comment from [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk) is an indirect answer to the question:

> Yes, but closed type is MyGeneric, not MyClass.
>   You can get current closed type as usual: typeof(MyGeneric), but this will 
>   not be MyClass of course, because this one is completely different type.

So the answer can be: 
It is wrong assuming MyClass is the same class than MyGeneric therefore it is not possible from generic type to get the type of MyClass.

Comment: I'd say that question itself has little sense, because as I said in another comment - you might have 100 classes inheriting from your `MyGeneric<TypeImplementingIMyInterface>`, not just MyClass, and so it's not really clear which one of them you want to get in your constructor. You can get all of them via reflection though (by searching for all types that inherit from `MyGeneric<T>`), like this: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(c => c.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyGeneric<T>)` in constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot edit the question. I would reformulate it as:

Remove: Is it possible, through reflection, to retrieve the type of the closed type (MyClass) from within the static constructor in the 
MyGeneric? If so, how?

Add: Are there (better) alternatives to make the static constructor aware about the type of derived types of the generic class than using the presented approach through the curiously recurring template pattern?

Comment: Well I have shown the way in the comment above: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(c => c.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyGeneric<T>)`, run from static constructor, will return a list of all types in current assembly which inherit from MyGeneric<T> (so, just one type - MyClass). Note that it is not correct to name MyClass "closed" type. MyGeneric<IMyInterface> is closed.

Comment: Yes. Your comment contains everything. As I tried to explain, I was wrong in considering "MyClass" the closed type.